# SQL -- SELECT is returning values where a column = True, but not when = False

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

%%read_sql

```
SELECT Language, IsOfficial
  FROM countrylanguage c
  JOIN country a 
    ON a.Code = c.CountryCode
 WHERE Name = "United States"
   AND IsOfficial = False;
```

Basically, I have this code that lists the languages in a country (based on existing tables).

When I set IsOfficial = True (is the language the official language of the country), it correctly displays the Languages with IsOfficial = True.

Even when I delete the row beginning with AND, is displays all the languages with True or False for IsOfficial.

However, when I set AND IsOfficial = False, it displays nothing at all.

Why isn't it showing the non-official languages?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `isOfficial` might actually be `NULL` rather than `false`.  You can try:

```
where not (isOfficial <=> true)
```

Comment: Null values always compare to false so if Isofficial were NULL then neither the original test would bring back that record.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have an actual boolean data type.

In MySQL, zero is considered as false, and non-zero value is considered as true. To use Boolean literals, you use the constants TRUE and FALSE that evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively.

Check the database type of IsOfficial.  If you are not satisfying the condition IsOfficial=false, then IsOfficial is not actually zero, it is something else.